# Groovy- append explicit arrays ie java arrays

Tags: java, arrays, groovy

Ive been working on an application that works with fairly low-level networking, ie. reading `byte[]` from an inputstream and sending `byte[]` to an outputstream, where the byte arrays are in a very specific format.

Now ive written a lot of code under the assumption that I can just append arrays with +, which, as I just found out just now, isnt possible - works only with `def a = []`, since thats a list.

This means now my project is full of code such as

```
public byte[] getHeaderBytes(){
    return MessageUtils.toBytesUINT(messageLength) + MessageUtils.toBytesUINT(messageType)
}
```

where the method also works on appending like

```
public static byte[] toBytesUINT(long... longs){
    byte[] rv = new byte[0]
    longs.each{
        byte[] arr = Longs.toByteArray(it)
        rv += arr[arr.size()-4 .. arr.size()-1]
        }
    return rv
}
```

(here im storing an unsigned 4byte integer into long, getting the bytes for the long using Guava and then getting the 4 least significant bytes that represent the unsigned int)

Now my question is, how should I go around to fixing my code with the least ammount of rewritting and/or do it in an elegant Groovy way?

EDIT:
after doing some more testing, it *is* possible with Object array but not primitive arrays, ie with code

```
    String[] testArray = ["A", "B", "C"]
String[] testArray2 = ["D", "E"]
println testArray + testArray2

Byte[] testArray5 = [0, 1, 2]
Byte[] testArray6 = [3, 4]
println testArray5 + testArray6

byte[] testArray3 = [0, 1, 2]
byte[] testArray4 = [3, 4]
println testArray3 + testArray4
```

the output is

```
    [A, B, C, D, E]                                                                                                                                                          
[0, 1, 2, 3 ,4]  


Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [B.plus() is applicable for argument types: ([B) values: [[3, 4]]                                    
Possible solutions: use([Ljava.lang.Object;), is(java.lang.Object), split(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), any(), size()                                                    
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [B.plus() is applicable for argument types: ([B) values: [[3, 4]]                                            
Possible solutions: use([Ljava.lang.Object;), is(java.lang.Object), split(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), any(), size()                                                    
        at main.run(main.groovy:11)
```

So, would simply working with Byte[] work? How dangerous would casting between Byte[] and byte[] be?

Comment: If you give the type it'll be a Groovy array, e.g., http://grails.asia/groovy-array-manipulation-examples. That's not a complete answer, but it's a start.

Comment: @DaveNewton edited question after some more testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after some more testing and research, Ive come to the following conclusion: as seen in the EDIT of the question, Object arrays are fine while primitive ones are not. So simply replacing the array types to Byte[] and then letting the GVM cast it to byte[] where needed does the trick.

Eg. this works:

```
public byte[] toBytes(int... ints){
    Byte[] rv = new Byte[0]
        ints.each{
            rv += (Byte[]) ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(it).array()
        }

        return rv
}

assert toBytes(1,2,3) == ([0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3] as byte[])
```